# how to extract attachment of email in MS Exchange?

Tags: exchange-server

First, I have to say I have no experience with Exchange so I have no code to show which I have already tried (as I don't know where to start).

I need to check emails that come in to a specific mailbox and parse an attachment that will be in csv format. (assume the attachment is called "data.csv" and the mailbox is "data@example.com").

Ultimately the data has to be imported into mysql. I am a dab-hand at php which will be available on the Windows server but I don't know if there is an API or anything I can interrogate.

How do I extract such data? Or can someone point me in the right direction?

Sorry for lack of 'trial' code.

Thanks

Comment: You want *Exchange Web Services* (EWS), which gives you a full SOAP API for Exchange. Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx for starters.

Comment: @sasfrog thanks thats exactly what I am after. Put it as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want Exchange Web Services (EWS), which gives you a full SOAP API for Exchange. Try [the EWS intro doco on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) for starters.